# Unable to access Core Data object from within collectionview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am scratching my head on this one.

I keep getting the following errror:

> ```
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSFaultingMutableSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
> ```
>
> 0x7ff3ec6b4590'

when I try to access the Photo Core Data model from within my collection view.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PinViewCollectionViewCell

      println(selectedPin!.attachedPhotos.count) // Returns 3
      println(selectedPin!.attachedPhotos[indexPath.row]) 
//^^Returns NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSFaultingMutableSet objectAtIndex:]:  
//unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff3ec6b4590'

             return cell
```

any Ideas how I can access the attachedPhotos individual items?

Comment: Most probably, `attachedPhotos` is an `(NS)Set` and not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
println((selectedPin!.attachedPhotos.allObjects as! NSArray)[indexPath.row]);
```

Comment: This worked as attached photos is NS Set but was able to convert it to the swift native using the above. as [Photo]